# How to Manage sql server ( running on windows server) via ansible (running on unix platform)?

Tags: windows, unix, ansible

I would like to know about How to Manage sql server (WINDOWS) (basically running some sql scripts) from an ansible instance running on a Unix platform. here is what I have done

contents of list.yml

```
---
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: connect to the db server
    shell: "invoke-sqlcmd -username \"username\" -password \"password\" -Query \"SELECT 1\""
```

```
[dbserver]
DBSERVER:1515 ansible_user=ansible
```

contents of ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory = ./development.txt
```

```
ERROR:

ansible-playbook playbooks/list.yml

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************
fatal: [DBSERVER]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host DBSERVER port 1515: Operation timed out", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************
DBSERVER          : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

TELNET WORKS

```
➜  ansible-test telnet DBSERVER 1515
Trying <ip address>...
Connected to DBSERVER.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Did you configure firewall rules to allow incoming traffic from port 1515 ?
Can you try ```ansible win -i inventory.txt  -m win_ping``` in command line and replace win with your hostname in the inventory and see the results.

Comment: If you haven't done yet, you can follow the guide to configure your windows machine to access it with ansible. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html

Comment: @Unsel I have tried to use telnet (see edit) and I am not using windows machine to establish connectivity to sql server, I am using a unix machine

Comment: AFAI, you should set the winRM in order to connect to your windows machine with ansible and execute tasks. Also you should set the ansible_connection=winrm in the host vars section of your inventory file so that Ansible Engine doesn’t just keep trying to connect to your Windows host via SSH

Comment: The `shell` Ansible module runs a command on the target you specified.  So here, Ansible tries to connect to your database server, using SSH to run the invoke-sqlcmd.  And you configured the database server with port 1515.  This tells Ansible to connect with SSH, using port 1515.  That is doubtful, SSH usually runs on port 22.  Your telnet confirms that port 1515 is opened, but not that is answers SSH.